Group by multiple nested fields and return result in BigQuery
I have a super market data and I want to list all super market branches in the city and then all the departments in that super market like grocery, cosmetics.
List sales for each department and finally calculate total sale in each department. So my response should look something like below



Branch
Department
Item
Total Amt




1
Grocery
Rice
150




Wheat
200



Cosmetics
Cream
300




Powder
100


2
Grocery
Oil
400




Dal
200



Cosmetics
Serum
150




Shampoo
100



I have tried the below query
SELECT branch, department, item , totalAmt
   FROM project.dataset.table 
   GROUP BY branch, department
   ORDER BY branch, department limit 100

But it is giving result like below:



Branch
Department
Item
Total Amt




1
Grocery
Rice
150


1
Grocery
Wheat
200


1
Cosmetics
Cream
300


1
Cosmetics
Powder
100


2
Grocery
Oil
400


2
Grocery
Dal
200


2
Cosmetics
Serum
150


2
Cosmetics
Shampoo
100



Is it possible to group by Branch and inside that Department and get results like how it is in the first table using BigQuery?

What is your expected result? @krishna

My expected result is the first table in the question, where it groups by Branch and then inside it groups by department and display the result @ArtBindu

Output formatting should be done in the application's GUI, not in sql code. You are expecting something from a relational database that it can't do very simply. Please do not add random unrelated tags to you question.

Are you 100% that the result of the query you have is the second table? It doesn't make any sense to me as you have 3 columns in the SELECT statement. The content of the 3rd column based on your query should be something like:
[{"item": "itemA", "totalAmt": 100}, {"item": "itemB", "totalAmt": 200}]

This is silly question according to db end ... @krishna

Use array_agg and struct function after summing to get the total amount in a subquery. See below
to create a sample data set
WITH ProductData AS (
    SELECT 1 AS branch, 'Grocery' AS department, 'Rice' AS item, 150 AS Value UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Grocery', 'Wheat', 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Cosmetics', 'Cream', 300 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Cosmetics', 'Powder', 100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Grocery', 'Oil', 400 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Grocery', 'Dal', 200 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Cosmetics', 'Serum', 150 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Cosmetics', 'Shampoo', 100 union all
     SELECT 1, 'Grocery', 'Wheat', 99 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Cosmetics', 'Cream', 33 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'Cosmetics', 'Powder', 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Grocery', 'Oil', 44 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Grocery', 'Dal', 22 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Cosmetics', 'Serum', 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Cosmetics', 'Shampoo', 13
)

to get the desired results
SELECT branch, 
       department,
       ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(item AS item, total_amt AS amount)) AS items
FROM (
    SELECT branch, department, item, SUM(value) AS total_amt
    FROM ProductData
    GROUP BY branch, department, item
)

GROUP BY branch, department
ORDER BY branch, department;
results

